# Cascaded if else in bash script

Tags: shell-script

i have dropbox account with files. Now, i need to check date, when file changed. If file changed, the script are download new file. If file not changed, i have echo "not downloaded". 
My file:

```
if [ -f /root/time.txt ]; then  
dropbox=`cat /root/time.txt | awk '{ print $12 }' | sed "s/,//g;s/\"//g"`  
data=`date -d $dropbox +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`  
echo $data  
dropbox2=`curl -X POST https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/get_metadata --header "Authorization: Bearer oc3DfYTzbxAAADDADAqWWh2nyEA21OgecbWedBNB02XRWj8janlbftW123DASy122W" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{\"path\":\"/wwe.txt\",\"include_media_info\":true}" | awk '{ print $12 }' | sed "s/,//g;s/\"//g"`  
data2=`date -d $dropbox2 +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`  
echo $data2 
if [$data -eq $data2]; then  
echo not downloaded 
else    
curl -X POST https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download --header "Authorization: Bearer oc3DfYTzbxAAADDADAqWWh2nyEA21OgecbWedBNB02XRWj8janlbftW123DASy122W" --header "Dropbox-API-Arg: {\"path\": \"/wwe.txt\"}" -o "./wwe.txt"    
fi
else
  curl -X POST https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/get_metadata --header "Authorization: Bearer oc3DfYTzbxAAADDADAqWWh2nyEA21OgecbWedBNB02XRWj8janlbftW123DASy122W" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{\"path\":\"/wwe.txt\",\"include_media_info\":true}" -o "./time.txt"   
fi
```

But,when i start script, i have this output:

```
1.sh: line 8: 1.sh: [20161008235133: not found
```

On line 8, i compare two dates (one from file, second from new checking of metada):

```
if [$data -eq $data2]; then
```

Where i have error ? Please help.

Comment: You're missing a (needed) space after `[` and before `]` on that line. This question would be more appropriate on the Unix & Linux or superuser SEs since this isn't a sysadmin question.

Comment: The `[` is just a synonym for the `test` command. You could write your statement as well as `if test $data -eq $data2 ; ...`.